# Clock on task bar doesn't update until mouse moves

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, clock, 20.10

Can anybody verify this please?

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10 yesterday, I noticed that the clock on the task bar doesn't automatically update any longer. I have my task bar set to auto-hide. When I move my mouse so that the task bar appears, the clock is always late. Only when I move my mouse once more, keeping the task bar open, the correct time appears.

I use the Gnome Dash-to-Panel extension.

This is not my idea of a clock. A clock should be readable in one glance, and should definitely not need to be prodded to give the right time.

**EDIT** (January 2021):

The behaviour has stopped. Both the clock and the battery percentage are correct whenever displayed. I notice that I'm still on Gnome Shell 3.38.1, but I'm on Mutter 3.38.2. My guess is that upgrading Mutter has removed the bug.

Comment: First thing to debug: is it still happening if you disable Dash-to-Panel? If no, then we know for sure it is Dash-to-panel in combination with Gnome Shell 3.38.

Comment: When not using Dash-to-panel, the task bar (now the top bar) doesn't hide. Or rather. I can't make it hide. The clock there updates correctly every minute without the need for mouse gestures.

Comment: I noticed it's not only the clock, but also the battery percentage. You need to move the mouse over the battery percentage to see the current value.

Comment: In the meantime, I can confirm the issue! (Ubuntu 20.10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue as well and it appears this is due to a bug in gnome-shell, which has been already corrected in version 3.38.2 (Ubuntu 20.10 comes with 3.38.1): https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2973

This is also tracked in the dash-to-panel tracker too: https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/1206

Comment: Yes, this appears to be what happens. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody verify this please?

Yes, I have the same issue using the "Hide top bar" extension only (no Dash-to-Panel).